# Why is my custom post query shortcode only showing 1 post?

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I created a shortcode for a custom post type so I can show the posts in a page. It works, except it only shows 1 post.

here the code... anyone know what's wrong?

```
// this is the shortcode function which includes the query 
function ea_get_location($atts){
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'destination' => null,
      'posts' => '10'

   ), $atts));

$ea_params = array(
  'post_type'=>'itineraries',
  'posts_per_page' => $posts,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'location',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $destination
      ))
  );

query_posts( $ea_params );
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$ea_var = '<article id="post-';
$ea_var .= get_the_ID();
$ea_var .= '" class="post-';
$ea_var .= get_the_ID();
$ea_var .= ' itineraries type-itineraries hentry">';
$ea_var .= '<header class="entry-header">';
$ea_var .= '<a href="';
$ea_var .= get_permalink();
$ea_var .= '#access" >';
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'itinerary-thumb' );
$thumb_url = $thumb['0'];
$ea_var .= '<img src="'.$thumb_url.'" class="attachment-itinerary-thumb wp-post-image" />';
$ea_var .= '</a><h2 class="entry-title">';
$ea_var .= '<a href="';
$ea_var .= get_permalink();
$ea_var .= '#access">'; 
$ea_var .= get_the_title();
$ea_var .= '</a></h2></header><div class="entry-summary">';
$ea_var .= get_the_excerpt();
$ea_var .= '</div></article>';   

    endwhile;    
// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
// return the variable for use in the shortcode
return '<div id="location-list" class="tax-location">'.$ea_var.'</div>';
}

// register the function as a shortcode
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('location', 'ea_get_location');
}
?>
```

Here is the new updated code

```
// this is the shortcode function which includes the query 
function ea_get_location($atts){
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'destination' => '',
      'posts' => -1

   ), $atts));

$ea_params = array(
  'post_type'=>'itineraries',
  'posts_per_page' => $posts,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'location',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $destination
      ))
  );

// The Query
$ea_itin_query = new WP_Query( $ea_params );

$ea_var = '';

while ($ea_itin_query->have_posts()) : $ea_itin_query->the_post();

global $post;

$ea_var .= '<article id="post-';
$ea_var .= get_the_ID();
$ea_var .= '" class="post-';
$ea_var .= get_the_ID();
$ea_var .= ' itineraries type-itineraries hentry">';
$ea_var .= '<header class="entry-header">';
$ea_var .= '<a href="';
$ea_var .= get_permalink();
$ea_var .= '#access" >';
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'itinerary-thumb' );
$thumb_url = $thumb['0'];
$ea_var .= '<img src="'.$thumb_url.'" class="attachment-itinerary-thumb wp-post-image" />';
$ea_var .= '</a><h2 class="entry-title">';
$ea_var .= '<a href="';
$ea_var .= get_permalink();
$ea_var .= '#access">'; 
$ea_var .= get_the_title();
$ea_var .= '</a></h2></header><div class="entry-summary">';
$ea_var .= get_the_excerpt();
$ea_var .= '</div></article>';   

endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

// return the variable for use in the shortcode
return '<div id="location-list" class="tax-location">'.$ea_var.'</div>';
}

// register the function as a shortcode
function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('location', 'ea_get_location');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only seeing one post because with each iteration of the loop you're overwriting the previous iteration's value of `$ea_var` on the line `$ea_var = '<article id="post-';`. declare `$ea_var` outside the while loop and change that line to append with `.=`

One other issue you've got is the use of `$post->ID` won't work unless you first globalize `$post`.

I also suggest you use a new instance of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `query_posts`, and then just [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after the loop, otherwise the shortcode will have unexpected results in some cases.

Comment: sorry, typo above, I meant [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)

Comment: How would I go about declaring the variable outside the loop? I mean what would the variable equal? (btw. I changed the $ea_var = '<article id="post-'; to $ea_var .= '<article id="post-'; and everything started working properly.

Comment: that works, though it gives a php undefined var error notice. just do `$ea_var = ''` before the `while` loop.

Comment: for instance, add `$ea_var = '';` before the 'query_posts()' line.

Comment: Oh ok, so It's ok to just leave it blank

Comment: I updated the code above.... is that what you meant?